# vb.net preincrement operator in function arg

Tags: .net, vb.net, arguments, operators, pre-increment

```
Sub V(N As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine(N)
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim N = 0
    For I As Integer = 1 To 5
        V(++N)
    Next
End Sub
```

VB.Net does not have preincrement operator, ++N wouldn't work outside of a function argument.
Why does this code compile?

Comment: Hint, it compile also if you write just +N or +++N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike C#, there is no increment operator in Vb.Net, the `+`/`-` symbols are treated as positive/negative arithmetic signs (or sum/rest if wrote between blankspaces, or if wrote before an assignation symbol like `+=`/`-=`), however, you can acchieve what you want in a similar way using the **[System.threading.Interlocked.Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.increment(v=vs.110).aspx)** function.

```
Imports System.Threading.Interlocked

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim value As Integer

        For count As Integer = 1 To 5
            Module1.Method(Increment(value))
        Next count 
    End Sub

    Sub Method(ByVal value As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine(value)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Unlike the - operator ("flip" the sign of a number) a + operator seems kind of pointless? I guess a question of why an operatator that doesn't really  do anything exists is considered offtopic?